# explicit_defaults_for_timestamp flag in MySQL server required in Apache Airflow

Tags: mysql, server, airflow

I have to setup Apache Airflow and using MySQL server to store metadata. Is it necessary to set **explicit_defaults_for_timestamp** flag in mysql server to use Airflow? Why?  It throws:

```
Global variable explicit_defaults_for_timestamp needs to be on (1) for mysql
```

However If the flag is set at the server level, another databases may affect. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

```
set global explicit_defaults_for_timestamp =1;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.